# How to select second element in web scraping with python?

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, tags

I tried:

```
    for row in soup.find("tbody").find_all("tr"):
     col = row.find_all("td")
     date =col[0].text
     revenue = col[1].text.replace("$", "").replace(",", "")
    
    tesla_revenue = tesla_revenue.append({"Date":date, "Revenue":revenue}, ignore_index=True)
tesla_revenue.head()
```

This was the result

|  | Date | Revenue |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | 2020 | 31536 |
| 1 | 2019 | 24578 |
| 2 | 2018 | 21461 |
| 3 | 2017 | 11759 |
| 4 | 2016 | 7000 |

so the result shows the table on the left, but I want one on the right, what should I do to select the next tbody?
(screenshot is in the link)

https://i.stack.imgur.com/3Lepx.png

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to select second table (`<tbody>` tag), you can do:

```
for row in soup.select("tbody")[1].find_all("tr"):  # <-- note the [1] to select second <tbody>
    # ...
```